# TIBASIC: How can one prompt a multivariable expression?

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

On the Ti-84 and Ti-89, I know that one can use "Define" to define a function with multiple variables. However, is there a way to use "Prompt" or something of the sort to define a function?

Suppose we have a very simple program that evaluates an expression (only an example):

```
Prompt a,b,c
Disp a^5-sqrt(c)/b
```

Instead of having to manually go into the Program Editor every single time to change the expression, how can we automatically Prompt the user to Define a function such as `eq(a,b,c)=a^5-sqrt(c)/b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! Use *y*-variables.

Functions are stored as *y*-variables on the TI-84, and these variables can be accessed by going to the VARS>Y-VARS>Function... menu. Then you can prompt the user for the equation with the *y*-variable being the input, like this:

```
Prompt Y1
```

Keep in mind that this is a string, meaning you need quotation marks at the beginning and end of your function when putting it in as the user. This can be cumbersome, and can be avoided by using `Input` instead, and storing it into a String variable (found in VARS>String...) first then to a *y*-variable.

```
Input "f(a,b,c): ",Str1
Str1→Y1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked on my 84! Would you mind just giving me the format for the 89? I'm not too familiar with the 89 version of TIBASIC.

Comment: Sorry, but I only have a TI-84 and don't know much about the 89. That said, the [TI-Basic Developer wiki](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/68k:home) has a ton of useful resources and documentation that may help you out. (I use it all the time)